# Reverse function or library for os.Getenv()

Tags: string, windows, go, hex, registry

I have a list of hexadecimal strings of REG_EXPAND_SZ type.
Sample:
reg,[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWAR\WOW6432Node], "Pathethic"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,49,00,4e,00,44,00,4f,00,57,00,53,00,\00,00
//Ignore the parsing and formatting part.

I need to convert it to the original string.

Expected output:
%systemroot%

Actual output:
C:\Windows

The problem is that when user initially run the command terminal expands it: reg add  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWAR\WOW6432Node /v Pathetic /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%systemroot%". Later the actual expanded string is used. For example: initial %systemroot% = actual C:\Windows. When I convert hex string to the regular one I get C:\Windows.

That is why I wonder if there any library or tool to get the key by providing value, meaning reverse. C:\Window :=os.Getenv(???).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func CToGoString(b []byte) string {
    var buf []byte
    for _, c := range b {
        if c != 0 {
            buf = append(buf, c)
        }
    }
    return string(buf)
}

func main() {

    str := "43003a005c00570049004e0044004f00570053000000" //%systemroot%
    bs, err := hex.DecodeString(str)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    //s := CToGoString(bs)
    result := CToGoString(bs)
    fmt.Println(result)

    f, err := os.OpenFile("rollback.bat", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0755)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    f.WriteString(result + "\n")

}
```

I have tried doing it manually but there are more expanded strings than I expected. Therefore, my program is limited. Please advise any solutions for this problem.
`

```
func reverseEnvVar(value string) string {
    // Use os.ExpandEnv() to expand environment variables in the input string
    expanded := os.ExpandEnv(value)

    // Check if the expanded string matches a known environment variable value
    switch expanded {
    case os.Getenv("SystemRoot"):
        return "%systemroot%"
    case os.Getenv("ProgramFiles"):
        return "%programfiles%"
    case os.Getenv("ProgramFiles(x86)"):
        return "%programfiles(x86)%"
    case os.Getenv("AppData"):
        return "%appdata%"
    case os.Getenv("LocalAppData"):
        return "%localappdata%"
    case os.Getenv("UserProfile"):
        return "%userprofile%"
    case os.Getenv("TEMP"):
        return "%temp%"
    case os.Getenv("TMP"):
        return "%tmp%"
    default:
        // If the expanded string doesn't match a known environment variable value,
        // return the original input value
        return value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a library that takes `C:\WINDOWS` and gives `%systemroot%` but it can easily be implemented using `os.Environ()`.

Imports:

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)
```

Hashmap for **value -> array of keys**:

```
func createEnvHashMap() map[string][]string {
    envMap := make(map[string][]string)

    for _, env := range os.Environ() {
        pair := strings.SplitN(env, "=", 2)
        if len(pair) == 2 {
            key := fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", strings.ToLower(pair[0]))
            value := pair[1]
            envMap[value] = append(envMap[value], key)
        }
    }

    return envMap
}
```

Function to return the list of **keys** given the **value**:

```
func getEnvKeysByValue(envMap map[string][]string, value string) ([]string, error) {
    keys, found := envMap[value]
    if !found {
        return nil, errors.New("no environment variable keys found for the value")
    }
    return keys, nil
}
```

Now you can use the **getEnvKeysByValue()** function in you main function:

```
func main() {

    // Create a map of environment variables and their keys
    envMap := createEnvHashMap()

    // This value can be replaced with the result variable in your main() function
    value := "C:\\WINDOWS"

    // Get environment variable keys by value
    keys, err := getEnvKeysByValue(envMap, value)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Environment variable keys:")
    for _, key := range keys {
        fmt.Println(key)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Environment variable keys:
%systemroot%
%windir%
```

This way there won't be a need to write switch case statements manually.

Make sure to call `createEnvHashMap()` only once and then call `getEnvKeysByValue(envMap, value)` as many times to get list of keys in O(1) time.