# Detect expand string in the string

Tags: string, windows, go, hex, registry

I need to detect expand string from the hex(2). For example there is original string in the command: `%SystemRoot%\system32\myapp.exe`.
After running the command:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyApp /v AppPath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%SystemRoot%\system32\myapp.exe"
```

The string will be converted to the hex(2):

```
"AppPath"=hex(2):43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,49,00,4e,00,44,00,4f,00,57,00,53,\00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,6d,00,79,00,\61,00,70,00,70,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,65,00,00,00
```

After decoding output: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\myapp.exe`
Expected output: `%SystemRoot%\system32\myapp.exe`

The problem is that I do not know how can I detect that expand string because in can be in any part of the directory as `%SystemRoot%\%Userprofile%\myapp.exe`.

For better understanding you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76626428/reverse-function-or-library-for-os-getenv/76631995#76631995) as well.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/hex"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "regexp"
)

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func createEnvHashMap() map[string][]string {

    envMap := make(map[string][]string)

    file, err := os.OpenFile("windowsEnv.txt", os.O_RDONLY, 0644)
    check(err)
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for scanner.Scan() {

        line := scanner.Text()
        pair := strings.SplitN(line, "=", 2)
        if len(pair) == 2 {
            key := fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", strings.ToLower(pair[0]))
            value := pair[1]
            envMap[value] = append(envMap[value], key)
        }
    }

    return envMap
}
func getEnvKeysByValue(envMap map[string][]string, value string) ([]string, error) {
    keys, found := envMap[value]
    if !found {
        return nil, errors.New("no environment variable keys found for the value")
    }
    return keys, nil
}

func escape(value string) string {
    specialChars := []string{"^", "&", "|", "<", ">", "(", ")", "%", "\\", "*"}
    for _, char := range specialChars {
        if strings.Contains(value, char) {
            value = strings.ReplaceAll(value, char, "^"+char)
        }
    }
    return value
}

func main() {


    value := "43003a005c00570049004e0044004f00570053005c00730079007300740065006d00330032005c006d0079006100700070002e006500780065000000"
    
    
        //formatting the string 
    

    hexBytes, err := hex.DecodeString(value)
    check(err)

    hexString := string(hexBytes)

    var dCom string

    if reg_percentPattern.MatchString(hexString) {
        dCom = escape(hexString) // add escape
    } else {


        envMap := createEnvHashMap()

        keys, err := getEnvKeysByValue(envMap, hexString)
        check(err)
        if len(keys) != 0 {
            dCom = keys[0]
        }

    }

    fmt.Println("final dCom", dCom)

}
```

I was thinking about extracting each part between \...\ but then it could be combination of several \...\...\ and you never know which one could fit and be the expand string like `C:\Users\Hp\AppData\Local\Temp`  which is for `%temp%`.

Comment: So you want [this code](https://go.dev/play/p/Br298Teif5G) to return `%SystemRoot%\system32\myapp.exe` instead of `C:\WINDOWS\system32\myapp.exe`? The only way I can think to do this would be a text search through the environmental variables (but that could have unpredictable results!). However a better solution is probably to prevent the expansion in the first place i.e. `reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyApp /v AppPath /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%SystemRoot%%\system32\myapp.exe"` (assuming whatever uses the key will expand variables).